# Problem with two kernels installed and '@fedora' entries in 'yum list'?

Tags: fedora, yum

FC11 beta upgraded to FC12. When I do yum list I see listing on the far right column as follows: 'fedora' 'installed' and '@fedora'. Previously I never had '@fedora' and only seemed to appear when I upgraded from FC11->FC12.

Also when i look at the kernels installed I have

```
kernel-PAE 2.6.30-0.97.rc.fc12 installed
kernel-PAE 2.6.31.5-127.fc12 @fedora
```

Why do I have two entries?

Comment: belongs on SuperUser

Answer (score 1):

kernels are in the "installonly" configuration, which means instead of doing an update (install new, then remove old) yum tells rpm to just install the new versions. This means you can install a new kernel, reboot to try it out but if it fails just reboot back to the old one.
Note that you may also want to look in "man yum.conf" and read about the installonly_limit, and the recent yumdb entries which affect removal of old installonly packages.

The @fedora part is documented in the yum man page, see the section titled "LIST OPTIONS". It is telling you what repository the kernel was installed from.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this:

```
# yum clean all
# yum update -y
```